# PHP referencing variable causes page to not load

Tags: php, class

I have the following class and sometimes (but not always) when I call the run function I get a "The localhost page isn’t working" message on the browser.

```
class className {
   private $string;

   public function run() {
      if ( isset($this->string) )
         echo 'yay';
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in the PHP error log?

Comment: @barmar I should have checked before. It has the following error
[Thu May 19 14:28:55.783149 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1060] AH00052: child pid 10229 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Comment: I don't see how that class can cause a problem like that. It sounds like you have a corrupted PHP installation.

Comment: @barmar it doesn't happen every time, only in 1 certain instance

Comment: That's consistent with my theory. If only part of the code is corrupted, you'll only crash if the script happens to do something that uses that part.

Comment: If PHP is crashing with a segmentation fault, that's a bug in PHP. I find it difficult to believe that the trivial class you showed above is running into a bug, though. There must be more going on.

Comment: @Barmar I've just uploaded the application onto a external web server and I get a 503 error

Comment: We'll need to see more of the code to have any chance at guessing what's wrong. There's nothing wrong in the little snippet you posted.

Comment: There's no chance of getting everything up, is there a few ideas of what might cause that error?

Comment: If we're to have any hope of helping you, you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It doesn't have to be the whole thing, just enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: So try removing parts of the script and see if the problem still happens. When you get to the smallest version that still breaks, post it.

Comment: I have posted the part that breaks it

Comment: We can't run that by itslef.